devops multiple yaml pipelines that push changes to the same branch
We have multiple yaml pipelines that use the same yaml to push a NuGet and update the .csproj file with the new version number. This works fine, until you run multiple pipelines that update a different NuGet each. In that case the local repository is out of sync.
I tried a lot of different things like fetching, puling etc. But nothing seems to work. Any input wold be appreciated.
The yaml looks like this.
trigger: none

pool: 'Self-hosted in Azure vms'

variables:
  - group: 'product Assembly info'
  - name: solution
    value: '**//$(ProjectFile)'
  - name: buildPlatform
    value: 'Any CPU'
  - name: buildConfiguration
    value: 'Release'
  - name: PackageVersion
    value: '$(Major).$(Minor).$(Build)$(Preview)'
  - name: Preview
    ${{if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'master') }}: 
      value: ''
    ${{ else }}:
      value: '-$(Build.SourceBranchName).$(PreviewBuild)'

steps:
- checkout: self
  persistCredentials: true
  fetchDepth: 0

- script: |
    git config --global user.email devops@company.com & git config --global user.name "DevOps"  
  workingDirectory: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)

- script: |
   git pull origin HEAD:$(Build.SourceBranchName)
  displayName: pull $(Build.SourceBranchName) 
  workingDirectory: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)

/// logic for creating nuget and updating a single .csproj file (different for every pipeline)

- script: |
   git add *.csproj
   git commit -m "$(ProjectFile) build $(PackageVersion)"
   git push origin HEAD:$(Build.SourceBranchName)
  displayName: commit package buildnumber
  workingDirectory: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)



Can you please let us know the error message and share more system.debug logs (can be enabled as the sample below) from your pipeline runs?

By the way, were those YAML pipelines pushing commits into the same .csproj file in the same branch? If so, may I assume you have several pipelines referencing different .yml definition files from the same branch that was updating the same .csproj file? But you mentioned your pipelines used the same YAML, which was very confusing why you created multiple pipelines based on the same definition. It could help understand how your issue was reproduced if you could share more details.

All pipelines are updating a different .csproj file in the same branch, but all pipelines are referencing the same .yml. I solved it, will write an answer with the working yml.

Glad to know the issue is resolved. Appreciate your time to share the solution and provide the working git pull command. Have a productive week ahead!

Below the .yml that does what I expected.
differences:

missing clean: true (thanks @alvin-zhao-msft).
pull should not have HEAD: but it is required for push.
pull is now at both the beginning of the yml and direct before the push.


trigger: none

pool: 'Self-hosted in Azure vms'

variables:
  - group: 'product Assembly info'
  - name: solution
    value: '**//$(ProjectFile)'
  - name: buildPlatform
    value: 'Any CPU'
  - name: buildConfiguration
    value: 'Release'
  - name: PackageVersion
    value: '$(Major).$(Minor).$(Build)$(Preview)'
  - name: Preview
    ${{if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'master') }}: 
      value: ''
    ${{ else }}:
      value: '-$(Build.SourceBranchName).$(PreviewBuild)'

steps:
- checkout: self
  persistCredentials: true
  fetchDepth: 0
  clean: true

- script: |
    git config --global user.email devops@company.com & git config --global user.name "DevOps"  
  workingDirectory: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)

- script: |
   git pull origin $(Build.SourceBranchName)
  displayName: pull $(Build.SourceBranchName) 
  workingDirectory: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)

/// logic for creating nuget and updating a single .csproj file (different for every pipeline)

- script: |
   git add *.csproj
   git commit -m "$(ProjectFile) build $(PackageVersion)"
   git pull origin $(Build.SourceBranchName)
   git push origin HEAD:$(Build.SourceBranchName)
  displayName: commit package buildnumber
  workingDirectory: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)



Based on your description and current pipeline definition, I have created a sample pipeline that successfully pushed the updated sample.csproj file into the $(Build.SourceBranchName) branch, from which the pipeline checked out the source code. The pipeline was able to achieve this without requiring additional git pull or fetch commands during the run.
Since our pipelines were running in a self-hosted agent pool, you may consider testing to enable the Clean property for your checkout step or the clean option for the pipeline workspace if possible.
Here is a sample for your reference.
variables:
  system.debug: true

jobs:
- job: myJob
  workspace:
    clean: resources # outputs | all 

  steps:
  - checkout: self
    persistCredentials: true
    fetchDepth: 0
    clean: true

  - script: |
      git config --global user.email "$(Build.RequestedForEmail)"
      git config --global user.name "Azure DevOps"
    displayName: git config user
    workingDirectory: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)

  # logic for creating nuget and updating a single .csproj file (different for every pipeline)

  - script: |
      git add *.csproj
      git commit -m "$(ProjectFile) build $(PackageVersion)"
      git push origin HEAD:$(Build.SourceBranchName)
    displayName: commit package buildnumber
    workingDirectory: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)


Thanks, clean was indeed part of the solution. But not enough. The pull is missing in your answer but required if running on multiple pipelines.

I see, your pipeline have new incoming commits that need to be retrieved by git pull. Thx for your update. Cheers.
